# Column not allowed here pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i am trying to create a procedure to add a new sale, but for some reason i am getting an error that says the column not allowed here

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AddSale
(
  In_CID               customers.CID%Type,
  In_EmpID             Employees.EmpID%Type,
  In_car_num           cars.car_num%Type,
  In_Pay_M             Sales.Pay_method%Type,
  In_Payment_duration  Sales.Pay_duration%Type,
  In_Payment_type      Sales.S_type%Type,     
  In_sh_id             Sales.sh_id%Type,
)
IS
  number := 0;
  Id_sale number;
BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO Sales(Sales_ID, CID, EmpID, car_num, S_time,
                    S_type, Pay_method, Pay_duration, sh_id)
  VALUES (Sales_ID_Seq.nextval, In_CID, In_EmpID, In_car_num, SYSDATE,
          In_Payment_type, In_Payment_M, In_Payment_duration, In_sh_id);
```

And here is the table definition:

```
create table Sales
(
  Pay_duration  number(15),
  Car_num       number(15),
  Sales_ID      number(15),
  S_type        varchar2(15),
  CID           number(15),
  Pay_method    varchar2(32),
  S_time        timestamp,
  EmpID         number(15),
  Sh_id         number(15),
  discount      number(5,3),
  Disc_status   varchar2(20),
  ApprovedBy    number(15)
);
```

Comment: Could you add your error message to your post? Thanks

Comment: Could this be caused by the trailing comma after  >>in_sh_id sales.sh_id%type,)<<

Comment: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: It really Really REALLY helps if you properly format your code. Please, edit your message and post SALES table description.

Comment: i added the sales table

Comment: I've formatted the code for you. Make it a habit to write clean code. It will help you spot errors (such as the comma after the last parameter). Also be consistent with your names (and with upper / lower case for readability). Why is it `EmpID` for the employees table, but `CID` for the customers table? I'd rather expect either `EID` for the employee or `CustID` for the customer, so as to keep one style. And what is so wrong with longer names? I'd just make it `employees.employee_id` and `customers.customer_id`. And is `car_num` the cars' ID?

Comment: On a side note: `s_time` is a `TIMESTAMP`. So why insert `SYSDATE`? `SYSTIMESTAMP` would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I've formatted the code in your request. You will see that proper formatting is a great help when coding.

In your declaration you have:

```
In_Pay_M
```

In your insert statement you have:

```
In_Payment_M
```

Then, there is a comma too many after your last parameter:

```
  In_sh_id             Sales.sh_id%Type,
)
```